# iTextSharp creating file in memory resulting corrupted file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, itext

I am trying to create a pdf file in MVC using iTextSharp. I do have a following simple used case. File is getting created but when I open the PDF I am getting error **file is corrupted unable to open the file**. Any idea/help ?

My Controller  code is a follows

```
public FileStreamResult GetPdfMemory()
{
            iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();


            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, mem);
            //pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Charts"));


            mem.Position = 0;

            FileStreamResult fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(mem, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf)
            {
                FileDownloadName = "chart_" + ".PDF"
            };

            return fileStreamResult;
}
```

View :
@Html.ActionLink("Pdf Memory", "GetPdfMemory", "Home", null, new { id = "download"})

FYI : When I try to use FileStream instead of MemoryStream all works fine. But I need to create PDF using memorystream.

Answer (score 0):

You manipulate (`mem.Position = 0`) and use (`new FileStreamResult(mem, ...)`) the `MemoryStream` before signalling iTextSharp that it can finalize the document. Thus, depending on whether implicit destruction of the `Document` and the `PdfWriter` or the use of the data in the memory stream comes first, you either have a PDF missing its closing parts or the closing parts (being written after you reposition the memory stream) overwriting the start of the data.

To signal to iTextSharp that it can finalize the document, please call `doc.Close()` before manipulating the memory stream or alternatively use the `Document` in a `using` block, e.g.:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
  // step 1
  using (Document document = new Document()) {
    // step 2
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
    // step 3
    document.Open();
    // step 4
    document.Add(new Paragraph("HelloWorldMemory"));      
  }
  HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
}
```

*(shamelessly copied from the sample [HelloWorldMemory.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter01&ex=HelloWorldMemory) from the [Webified iTextSharp Examples](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx)) for [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/))*

Using `using` implicitly causes the `Document` to be closed.

Comment: In MVC when returning FileStreamResult as an action result we cannot use using clause. We will always get "Cannot acess a close stream" error. FYI, I am trying this in .NET MVC.

Comment: In that case try the other alternative in the answer.

Comment: That is the one I posted in my original question, unless you are referring to some other alternative.

Comment: FYI : When I tried doc.close() before manipulation memory stream i get "Cannot access a closed stream"

Comment: You may want to set the CloseStream stricter if the PDFWriter to false then.

Comment: Setting **pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;** gave same result. I am not sure what is going on. Something really weird.

Comment: That's really weird... The stream used by a writer with CloseStream false is not closed when the writer is.